# How can I send a tn3270 compatible screen to a terminal emulator?

Tags: delphi, terminal-emulator

I want to test a terminal emulator I have, but I really don't want to learn Hercules 360, before someone mentions that.

I'm not after creating mainframe applications, what really want to do is learn how to send tn3270 screens for display on a terminal emulator. My reason is simple; I have a set of screens from a customer where their layout, look and feel, etc are all fixed. I want to test my client software against those screens without having to trail all the way out to the customers site to do it in the first instance.

Failing that, does anyone know of a "less intense" method of simulating a tn3270 environment complete with fields, attributes, etc.. ?

I found a reference to an old freeware product called miniFrame by CodeCutter, but the website for it no longer exists and google returns various links that just point back to it.

Thanks

Comment: What about [TN Bridge Host Integration Pack](http://www.cybelesoft.com/en/host-integration-pack.html) ? They claim to have a TN3270 emulation component.

Comment: It does. But its a client side component, not a server. You still need mainframe, or mainframe emulator to use it/test it.

Comment: In serial comms days, we'd just record the data stream and then replay that again and again. No idea how you do it with this terminal, but that's what you are looking for.

Comment: or if you can record the data stream you might then replay it back with a simple ECHO program.

Comment: I might have to do that.

I found the TN3270Server class from the Open3270 project, but its not working correctly and there is no documentation. Does anyone have an example on how to use this class?